# How to enforce a "has a" relationship and protect the object that "is had"

Tags: oop

Given the following code:

```
Class User{
  Task m_Task;  
  public function getTask("Do work") { return m_Task; }
}

Class Project{
  Task m_Task;  
  public function getTask("Do work") { return m_Task; }
}

Class Task {
  private m_Name;
  public Task(name) { m_Name = name; }
}

Class Evil {
  new Task = Error
}
```

In a language that does not support multiple inheritance, nested classes, or private classes, (private constructor not an option), how can you design a requirement that Task is only ever instantiated through User or Project? Ideally using only language constructs instead of code. Is there a design pattern?

Comment: *shudder*  I hate the "has a" and "is a" terms.

Comment: Brian, why ?  As is, they're clear and concise.  Care to point out the other nomenclature ?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with them, but you can say "inherits", "composes", and "aggregates" instead.

Comment: @jim They seem clear on the surface, but once you go digging, there is a hidden vagueness and simplicity that can easily lure one into bad design.  Chaos' options stand out better and make it harder for one to take the wrong path.

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @Brian, Good point.  Sometime I want to convey a broad description with out bogging down in details. "has-a" does that.  Only when I want to describe in detail does composes and aggregate come into play.  is-a and has-a pop up in my mind a lot quicker ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite an answer, you can construct a task from elsewhere but you need a valid task instance to do it..

```
public class Task {
   public Task (User u, String name)
   {
     if (u==null) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("that's cheating");
     this.name=name;
   }
}
```

Utlimately, if you're creating the requirement that Task be external to user then something else needs to be able to load task's constructor so I don't think it's possible.

What's the purpose of this question? Does this relate in any way to some real-world situation?

Answer (score 0):

It seems somewhat quixotic, but I suppose you write Task a constructor that requires a User as an argument and does some handshaking back and forth to link the User to the Task, requiring that the User does not already have a Task.